# Data not inserting into table

Tags: php

My registration system has suddenly broken. Originally it just required three pieces of data - username, password and email - but I've now included a verification code that is generated by the script, and I have no idea what is breaking it. I've troubleshot, and no error is coming up. All it says is "Error", which is the text I've told it to output if the database insertion doesn't work.

Any ideas?

**register.php**

```
require 'core/init.php';
require 'lib/password.php';

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$randomString = substr(md5(rand()),0,7);

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user, pass, email, ver) VALUES (:user, :pass, :email, :ver)");
$query->bindParam(':user', $user);
$query->bindParam(':pass', $pass);
$query->bindParam(':email', $email);
$query->bindParam(':ver', $randomString);

if($query->execute()) {
$_SESSION['reqact'] = 1;
header('Location: index.php');
}
else {
echo "Error.";
}
```

**core/init.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = new PDO('logindataisfine');

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $i = $_SESSION['id'];
}
else if($_SESSION['reqact'] == 1) {
    echo "Please <a href='activate.php'>verify your account.</a>";
    }
else {
echo "Please <a href='login.php'>log in.</a>";
$guest = True;
}
```

Comment: Check errors that happened during executing query

Comment: A. It didn't suddenly break, you made changes that broke it. B. Output a useful error, using the mysql error messages.

Comment: `$ver` is not used anywhere, there's no need to define it

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right - so? He also doesn't have $foo or $bar - what does that matter?

Comment: add± $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); after your prepare. That will show you the error

Comment: Then it's `$email` that's not defined anywhere.

Comment: I know I broke it, there is absolutely no need to be so snide about it. I've not used `$ver` anywhere as far as I can see?

Comment: You have `$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` but no `$email= $_POST['email'];`

Comment: That's the one! I had deleted the definition of $email. Brill - thanks so much!

Comment: Suggestions: Set error reporting to -1, set PDO error mode to Exception (can't find docs for that, see the pdo['options'] key here:  https://github.com/jeremykendall/flaming-archer/blob/develop/config/global.php), wrap the whole shebang in a try/catch, and output the exception message.

Comment: @CuriousCabbage it's not being snide - if you can't even take responsibility for breaking it, how do you expect to fix it? Your whole post is "I'm a victim" and the problem could have been solved on your own if you owned it. "My code just prints 'error'" well, you told it to print error. It's the tone that reflects how you view your own work.

Comment: The code as it is should have thrown a notice when you tried to use $email, so you need to update your php.ini to turn on error reporting.

Comment: Let's close this question then. @CuriousCabbage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` but no `$email= $_POST['email'];`

not having that variable will break your query.

As Marcel (Korpel) pointed out in his comment below (*thank you Marcel*), you could check if any of the variables are set or empty.

For example:

```
if(isset($_POST['variable'])){ // do or show something }
```

or

```
if(empty($_POST['variable'])){ // do or show something }
```

Comment: And to be more secure, I would check for `empty` or at least `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an error in your sql statement (is ver the actual column name?)

To get the sql error, where you are echoing your "Error" string also throw in:
print_r($query->errorInfo());

```
if($query->execute()) {
$_SESSION['reqact'] = 1;
header('Location: index.php');
}
else {
echo "Error.";
print_r($query->errorInfo()); //<- print sql error
}
```

once you know exactly what the error is you'll have an easier time fixing it.